# Deploying static content not updating css

Tags: magento2, static-content, less-css, porto-theme

As far as I understand it, In order to change the style of an email, I need to override the _email-extended.less file. I go to the path below

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/Porto/web/css/source/_email-extended.less
```

and make my changes/add classes but it doesnt seem to affect any of my generated static content css files. It simply does nothing. Ive tried deleting the folder where I assume it shows up

`pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css`

but when I look, none of the files have been modified, it still generates the same files it was before it got deleted. The best i can tell is im doing the changes in the wrong location, however i am not sure where to look if not in the directory listed above...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your configuration, there's a few folders you might need to clear before your changes are caught. Are you using server-side or client-side rendering? Are you in production mode, default mode or developer mode?

Assuming you are in production mode, most likely you need to empty the following folder
`var/view_preprocessed` and `var/cache`.

I usually run `rm -R var/cache/*;rm -R var/view_preprocessed/*`.

You can review the documentation here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

Comment: I am currently running in developer mode and I am running server side processing, Im not positive how to check, but when I run ```php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f``` it generates the new css, but it doesnt seem to read the less files and just goes off of whatever it was originally

Comment: your solution worked, basically the files in view_processed were the ones that were building the static content and not the updates that I had made, once i deleted both, it worked. thanks!